# Этимология и статус междометия «ё-моё»

Tags: этимология, лексика, стилистика, выбор-слов, история

Бытует мнение, что междометие *ё-моё* является матерным. Верно ли оно? Как произошло это слово?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то это разговорное междометие, оно выражает удивление с оттенком досады, разочарования. В то же время это молодёжный сленг, эвфемизм, заменяющий нецензурную лексику, т.е. "скрытое матерное".

С буквы «ё» начинается большинство русских слов и словосочетаний, заменяющих нецензурную лексику и выражающих досаду, огорчение, недоумение, удивление, а иногда и радость. Например, «ёпрст», «ёперный театр», «ёксель-моксель», «ёкарный бабай», «ёлки-палки». Буква «ё» (звук «йо») имеет для русского человека особое значение и обладает, по мнению многих исследователей языка, мощной энергетикой. Если вы ударитесь мизинцем о ножку стола, вы не вскрикнете «Ой!» или «Ах!», а воскликнете: «Ё!» Всем с детства знакомо предложение «Казнить нельзя помиловать», которое без запятой невозможно верно истолковать. То же самое свойство, что и запятая, имеет и буква «ё». Без неё смысл многих выражений был бы нам не понятен. Например, «В ближайшие дни страна передохнет от холода» или «Выпили все». «Ё-моё!»

Эвфемизм «ё-моё», по мнению большинства исследователей, появился в русском языке, как ни странно, именно благодаря культуре, а не её отсутствию. В некоторых ситуациях (например, в присутствии женщин или пожилых людей, на рабочем месте или в театре) употребление нецензурной лексики считается дурным тоном. Однако неприятные или, напротив, радостные события могут произойти где угодно. В первую минуту эмоционального всплеска, не контролируя себя, человек, конечно, выкрикнет букву «Ё», с которой начинаются большинство ругательств русского языка. Однако, опомнившись, он скажет первое, что придёт в голову: как правило, это будет слово, подходящее по смыслу и рифмующееся с высказанным. Так и произошло выражение «ё-моё». Таким же образом образовался, например, и эвфемизм «ёпрст», когда бранившийся человек сделал вид, что просто перечисляет буквы алфавита. Поэтому «ё-моё» - ничто иное как завуалированное ругательство.

Однако некоторые ученые считают, что многие русские ругательства или заменяющие их слова в древности использовались как посылы или заклятия. Отсюда и запрет на их употребление. Поэтому и выражение «ё-моё» тоже могло быть из числа подобных «мантр». Также может быть, что «ё-моё» – это просто сокращённое до междометия нецензурное словосочетание, обозначающее гениталии и их принадлежность говорящему.

Источник: http://russian7.ru/post/chto-oznachaet-vyrazhenie-yo-moyo-na-samo/